# Python, Remove duplicate values from dataframe column of lists

Tags: python, list, set, tuples

I've got a dataframe column containing lists, and I want to remove duplicate values from the individual lists.

```
d = {'colA': [['UVB', 'NER', 'GGR', 'NER'], ['KO'], ['ERK1', 'ERK1', 'ERK2'], []]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to remove the duplicate 'NER' and 'ERK1' from the lists.

I've tried:

```
df['colA'] = set(tuple(df['colA']))
```

I get the error message:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove duplicates values from the list using `apply()` method of pandas function as follows.

```py
import pandas as pd
d = {'colA': [['UVB', 'NER', 'GGR', 'NER'], ['KO'], ['ERK1', 'ERK1', 'ERK2'], []]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['colA'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))

#output
0    [NER, UVB, GGR]
1               [KO]
2       [ERK2, ERK1]
3                 []
Name: colA, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

problem is that you have a tuple of lists, thats why set command doesnt work. You should iterate over entire tuple.

`ans = tuple(df['colA'])     for i in range(len(ans))     df['colA'].iloc[i]=set(ans[i])`